# SQL Server vs MongoDB - Tamanho em Disco

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, mongodb, tabela-banco-de-dados

Hoje tenho uma tabela no SQL Server bem grande e recebe dados o tempo todo referente a algumas máquina da fábrica.

Isso está causando um problema de grande consumo de disco, o tamanho da tabela não pára de aumentar.

Se eu passar essa tabela para um banco não relacional como o MongoDB, quanto eu ganharia em termos de espaço em disco? Existe algum jeito de realizar essa conta?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

Essas coisas dependem muito. O consumo tem mais a ver com sua modelagem do que com o banco de dados, e a forma de modelar um é diferente de modelar em outro.

Ao contrário do que as pessoas imaginam, MongoDB ou qualquer ferramenta não opera milagres. Minha percepção é que será pior porque ele é otimizado para trabalhar com documentos, espera-se dele entradas grandes e sem um padrão, então cada documento deve ter metadados para "explicar" o que é aquilo. Mas sem testar e medir o caso específico eu não posso afirmar.

Bancos de dados relacionais são muito otimizados para consumo de espaço e processamento e as implementações atuais são muito flexíveis, além de ser fácil controlar transações nele. Sua deficiência está basicamente em acesso mais complicado com precisa fazer relações (mas traz vantagens também) e maior dificuldade de escala vertical (mas que é menos necessária que em outras soluções).

Precisa ver formas de reduzir esses dados, ver se está usando os tipos certos, do jeito certo, se pode fazer algum tipo de compressão. O MongoDB faz alguma compressão por padrão, mas só porque ele desperdiça recursos demais para não fazer. Se a compressão ajuda então faça no SQL Server, já que isso não é padrão.

Se dados entram sem parar no banco de dados em qualquer tecnologia vai ocupar muito espaço e não existe solução miraculosa que mude isso. É possível fazer um trabalho árduo de engenharia para achar soluções.

Em linhas gerais é isso, não dá para ajudar mais sem conhecer o problema com mais profundidade.

Comment: Muito obrigado Maniero!...acho que deu pra ter uma ideia, nesse caso então não compensaria uma migração, vou estudar mais sobre compressão e ver se é possível seguir nessa linha